# Center empty DIV with image

Tags: image, center

I am trying to center an empty element DIV with a defined image in CSS.
I would like to center the DIV with the image.

It is hard to explain.

Here is live demo http://www-kodovani.cz/test.html
- I would like to get centered element #button same as text above. I know the element is centered but the image is ignoring it.

Comment: Please include your code here, and perhaps a link to your site or a jsfiddle as an additional resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is adding "margin: 0 auto;" to the div element ?

```
.nase-portfolio {
width: 180px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 70px;
background: url(images/button.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#button {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```